# Convergence of $\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n^p - n^q}$, where $0 < q < p$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I would like to test the convergence of the following series.

> Test : $\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n^p - n^q}$, where $0 < q < p$

**My attempt**

I approached the problem with comparison test,

$$\frac{1}{n^p - n^q} = \frac{1}{n^q(n^{p-q}- 1)} < \frac{1}{n^q}$$

since $n^a >1$, $\forall n \ge 2, a>0$.

It is well-known that if $q > 1$, then $\sum \frac{1}{n^q}$ converges.

I'm currently stuck at the problem of how to address the cases of $q > 0$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/651009/42969

Comment: Btw, your estimate $\frac{1}{n^q(n^{p-q}- 1)} < \frac{1}{n^q}$  holds only if $n^{p-q} > 2$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\frac {n^{p}} {n^{p}-n^{q}} \to 1$ so the given series converges iff $\sum \frac 1 {n^{p}}$ converges iff $p >1$. As long as $0<q<p$ we don't have to worry about whether $q>1$ or not.